# Add property to a list?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a list with a lot of objects `List<MyObjects>` - Im iterating through this list and reading the objects. Thats all fine. I just relized now, what it would be awesome if I could add 1 more special value to this List - not an Object, just 1 value of something (a string).

I could now create a class like

```
class Needless
{
  public List<MyObjects> MyList { get; set; }
  public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

but Im trying to avoid that. I just really need 1 string with an input every `List<MyObjects>` Any ideas?

Comment: Is `MyValue` independent of the values in `MyList`?

Comment: Would it work in this situation to add the `MyList` and `MyValue` to a `Dictionary`, like `Dictionary<string, List<MyObjects>>`?

Comment: @BrianSnow I think so. I was hoping there are easier ways ^^ ... something like: List.AddProperty(MyValue) - I mean Dictionary is not "hard", just looking weird.

Comment: List should add some property like "Tag"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Tuple<string, List<MyObject>>` is an option. However, if you are going to use this pairing *a lot*, I would advise creating a custom class for it to be more explicit - either like you have done, or by deriving `List<MyObject>` and adding the string as a property.

If you are working "in scope" you could always make anonymous types:

```
var t = new { TheString = "", TheList = new List<MyObject>() };
var list = t.TheList;
var s = t.TheString;
```

But this only really has benefit in the scope of a method. The compiler can give IntelliSense for this and it is strongly-typed at compile time.

Or if you really want to go all out, use `ExpandoObject` from `System.Dynamic`:

```
var expando = new ExpandoObject();
expando.List = new List<MyObject>();
expando.TheString = "";
```

This is typed in-line without any IntelliSense support, and will invoke the DLR. `ExpandoObject` simply uses an `IDictionary<string, object>` under the hood, so...

```
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
```

...is valid.

The last option is a *little* tongue-in-cheek. It'll work, but the development experience against it isn't ideal compared to other options. That said, we use `ExpandoObject` in our test code, but I can't remember why. One can only hope the reasoning was sound, but it was likely a developer getting giddy with new toys...

Answer (score 3):

you can inherit the List and simply add your property, it's a bit cleaner than composite the List inside another class

Answer (score 0):

You could extend a List implementation with your Needless class. That way you can still treat your list as a list.